# Store form data in a database for any number of dynamic forms with different textboxes and dropdowns.

Tags: php

I have a website with two parts user and admin side.In admin side we had given the option to create the form.In the form he can add any number of text boxes and drop downs.But our problem is once he creates the form how to add the text box data or drop down data in database because in one form he can create 5 text boxes and in other form he create 10 text boxes.Please provide me the solution

Comment: -1 you need to give us a clue! provide some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can create any number of forms, with any number of input fields, its probably the best to just store the form data as text in form of a serialized array.

You can use php [`serialize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) and [`unserialize`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) to convert your arrays and reconvert your serialized arrays.

You can create a table, lets say for instance `entries` with a `form_id` column as a foreign key which is linked to the `form` table and a `form_data` column where you store your data as a `serialized array`. That way you can support every kind of forms

This sollution actually depends on how you are later using your data. Because its not that easy to filter with sql.

Comment: Actually the forms will be created by admin but the user at the front end will enter the data into the text boxes and drop downs created by admin.Again we need to show this data in the reports.

Comment: Just extended my answer a little bit for further understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate table for each form the admin creates.Then whatever data user enters in that form can be stored in that table.If admin create one form with 5 textboxes and other form with 2 textboxes then creating a separate table will do your task. If you need only one form active at a time then you can either use alter table query to change existing table or you can delete old table and add a new one.

Comment: suppose if we have 100 forms should we create 100 separate tables all the forms will be active in my project.

Comment: As far as i know, you have to maintain separate table for each form.